How can I detect the two ellipses on a roulette wheel?
I have the image below:

How can I detect the two ellipses below:

I want to have a mask only of this enclosed area to later detect the ball.
This is what I have tried but it does not find it correctly:
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load the image
image = cv2.imread('roulette.png')

# Convert the image to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Apply Gaussian blur to reduce noise
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)

# Perform edge detection using Canny
edges = cv2.Canny(blurred, 30, 150)

# Find contours in the edge-detected image
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(edges.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Loop over the contours
for contour in contours:
    # Fit an ellipse to the contour
    if len(contour) >= 700:
        ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(contour)
        # Draw the ellipse on the original image
        cv2.ellipse(image, ellipse, (0, 255, 0), 2)

# Show the image with detected ellipses
cv2.imshow("Ellipses", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

How can I solve this issue? Any suggestions or another method? Thanks!

what is the goal of your goal?

i want to have a mask only of this enclosed area to later detect the ball

just use AI. requires no thinking, just annotating a few pictures.

That is not my question. I have a way to detect the ball. Right now I only want to detect the ellipses.

Hi, @Blind0ne!!! Will the pictures always be taken at the same angle and with the same scale? Or can these two variables vary?

@anmabe the angle of the camera might change slightly that's why i would like to detect the ellipses automatically if it's possible. The scale will stay the same.

Any ideas or pointers anyone?

Hi @Blind0ne! Sorry, I was caught up with some work I had to get done... I think your answer is quite good. What I was thinking about was to first identify the inner ellipse, since it is the easiest and more precise one to detect. Then define a new ellipse centered where the inner one is, but with an increased radius of however many pixels wide the area to detect the ball is. Thus, you would have now identified the area where the ball will land. However, this approach would only work if the scale is kept constant.

Found a good answer to my question here.
Also this example code helped me to detect those:
#!/usr/bin/python

'''
This example illustrates how to use cv.ximgproc.EdgeDrawing class.

Usage:
    ed.py [<image_name>]
    image argument defaults to board.jpg
'''

# Python 2/3 compatibility
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import random as rng
import sys

rng.seed(12345)

def main():
    try:
        fn = sys.argv[1]
    except IndexError:
        fn = 'board.jpg'

    src = cv.imread(cv.samples.findFile(fn))
    gray = cv.cvtColor(src, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    cv.imshow("source", src)

    ssrc = src.copy()*0
    lsrc = src.copy()
    esrc = src.copy()

    ed = cv.ximgproc.createEdgeDrawing()

    # you can change parameters (refer the documentation to see all parameters)
    EDParams = cv.ximgproc_EdgeDrawing_Params()
    EDParams.MinPathLength = 50     # try changing this value between 5 to 1000
    EDParams.PFmode = False         # defaut value try to swich it to True
    EDParams.MinLineLength = 10     # try changing this value between 5 to 100
    EDParams.NFAValidation = True   # defaut value try to swich it to False

    ed.setParams(EDParams)

    # Detect edges
    # you should call this before detectLines() and detectEllipses()
    ed.detectEdges(gray)

    segments = ed.getSegments()
    lines = ed.detectLines()
    ellipses = ed.detectEllipses()

    #Draw detected edge segments
    for i in range(len(segments)):
        color = (rng.randint(0,256), rng.randint(0,256), rng.randint(0,256))
        cv.polylines(ssrc, [segments[i]], False, color, 1, cv.LINE_8)

    cv.imshow("detected edge segments", ssrc)

    #Draw detected lines
    if lines is not None: # Check if the lines have been found and only then iterate over these and add them to the image
        lines = np.uint16(np.around(lines))
        for i in range(len(lines)):
            cv.line(lsrc, (lines[i][0][0], lines[i][0][1]), (lines[i][0][2], lines[i][0][3]), (0, 0, 255), 1, cv.LINE_AA)

    cv.imshow("detected lines", lsrc)

    #Draw detected circles and ellipses
    if ellipses is not None: # Check if circles and ellipses have been found and only then iterate over these and add them to the image
        for i in range(len(ellipses)):
            center = (int(ellipses[i][0][0]), int(ellipses[i][0][1]))
            axes = (int(ellipses[i][0][2])+int(ellipses[i][0][3]),int(ellipses[i][0][2])+int(ellipses[i][0][4]))
            angle = ellipses[i][0][5]
            color = (0, 0, 255)
            if ellipses[i][0][2] == 0:
                color = (0, 255, 0)
            cv.ellipse(esrc, center, axes, angle,0, 360, color, 2, cv.LINE_AA)

    cv.imshow("detected circles and ellipses", esrc)
    cv.waitKey(0)
    print('Done')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(__doc__)
    main()
    cv.destroyAllWindows()

